# How to sum or average mulitple overlapping time intervals with lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a log of many years of meditation sittings, each with a start and end time. I want to create nice plots of my most active times of the day. (In other words, how often relatively I am meditating at 7am versus other times of day?)

```
     ID           StartTime             EndTime
1  2679 2019-03-23 07:00:00 2019-03-23 07:30:00
2  2678 2019-03-22 07:00:00 2019-03-22 07:30:00
3  2677 2019-03-21 07:00:00 2019-03-21 07:30:00
4  2676 2019-03-20 07:00:00 2019-03-20 07:30:00
5  2675 2019-03-19 07:00:00 2019-03-19 07:30:00
6  2674 2019-03-18 09:00:00 2019-03-18 09:30:00
7  2673 2019-03-18 09:00:00 2019-03-18 09:30:00
8  2672 2019-03-18 09:00:00 2019-03-18 10:00:00
9  2671 2019-03-15 07:00:00 2019-03-15 08:00:00
10 2670 2019-03-14 07:00:00 2019-03-14 08:00:00
```

dput version:

```
structure(list(ID = 2679:2670, StartTime = structure(c(1553324400, 
1553238000, 1553151600, 1553065200, 1552978800, 1552899600, 1552899600, 
1552899600, 1552633200, 1552546800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), EndTime = structure(c(1553326200, 1553239800, 
1553153400, 1553067000, 1552980600, 1552901400, 1552901400, 1552903200, 
1552636800, 1552550400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can hack this by turning each day into an 1440 element array of included/excluded minutes and summing these up. Getting something like this
[image: Count of times when I was mediating minute by minute]

But I feel like there must be a better way. Probably using `Interval` object from `lubridate` and/or `dplyr`. But I haven't worked out how to do this.

Comment: please provide data using `dput()`

Comment: provide us with an expected output. I will be easier to help